# XML to Object conversion

Tags: java, xml

We can convert XML to object using any one of these(SAX,DOM,STAX,XSTREAM). Please tell me ,What is the criteria to pick one of these.

Answer (score 1):

SAX and DOM are different style parsers.  The main difference between them is that DOM will load the entire document into memory and allow you to perform operations (such as XPath queries) on it.  SAX will parse the XML document and call back into your code.

As a general rule of thumb, if you are asking, I think DOM is probably easier to work with at first, and probably won't be an issue unless you need to load a huge XML document into memory.

If you are looking to convert XML into a Java objects, there are frameworks that will do this for you, and abstract the XML parsing layer.  I've used Castor in the past, but there are probably newer frameworks that you can find with a quick Google.

Answer (score 1):

This benchmark comparison by Marco Tedone might help you out on picking a parsing method.

[XML unmarshalling benchmark in Java: JAXB vs STax vs Woodstox](http://java.dzone.com/articles/xml-unmarshalling-benchmark)

Answer (score 1):

[**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) is the Java standard for coverting domain objects to/from XML.  An implementation is included in the JDK/JRE starting in Java SE 6.  There are also other open source implementations available (I'm the [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead).

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted

Since you mentioned XStream, below is an article I wrote comparing JAXB and XStream:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

**DOM** is an in memory data structure that represents XML data as a tree of `Node` objects.  There are extensions of `Node` that represent elements, attributes, text, etc.

**SAX/StAX** are very light weight APIs that allow you to work with very large XML documents.

Answer (score 0):

DOM parser is tree-modeled. It will generally construct a complete tree for the XML documents based on embedding structure in the XML file. The advantage of DOM is you can randomly access any XML nodes, their sub-nodes, siblings, and also attributes. Obviously, the disadvantage is that this method consumes too much RAM since it tries to load all XML data in the memory.

As to SAX, it's event-based. It reads in XML data as stream, and you can override those functions when certain events(document start/end, an open/close tag encountered, etc.) happen. This parser is much more powerful when you deal with large XML data. However, as you can guess, when the **stream data** flows away, you can never get them back. Thus random access is impossible for SAX parser.

Concerning StAX, it's a relatively new model, compared to SAX and DOM, and in fact, was designed as a median between the two previous models. It enables you to both read and write XML Documents. The idea of StAX is to keep the stream characteristic of SAX. But this **stream** is different from that of SAX. we call it as **pull-streaming** while for SAX, it's **push-streaming**. In the push-streaming model, the parser  the parser sends the data whether or not the client is ready to use it at that time. On the contrary, the pull-streaming model will explicitly ask for XML data, only when our application are ready to consume the data.

In my humble opinion, StAX is the best choice, but DOM and SAX could also be a nice start for understanding the pros and cons.

**Note**: due to my limited knowledge, I don't know much about **XSTREAM**. Hope some other guys could help you !